# Pushing hex code value of background-color through .text()

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to read the hexadecimal code from the `<span>` tag and put it as the `background color` of the same tag - using the following code with jQuery:
It is working fine for now but is specific and uses variables instead of dynamically picking up the value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var primeCol = $('.colorBlocks div:eq(0) span').text();
  $(".colorBlocks div:eq(0) span").css("background-color", primeCol);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>#0099cc</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Primary Color 2 is #OOffcc</span>
</div>
```

I need to make it dynamic so it uses the `$(this).text()` maybe without the use of variable for any `<span>` tag. Also, to identify the hex code from within the text like in the second `<span>` tag. Please can anybody help? I am struggling with this.

Comment: Where is colorBlocks

Comment: Can You please specify Your question? The code You show does not work as is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can provide a function to the `css()` method which will be used to evaluate each element in the matched set. From there you need to use `:first-child` to match the first element within each child `div` instead of the first one of them all. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colorBlocks div:first-child span').css('background-color', function() {
    return $(this).text();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colorBlocks">
  <div>
    <span>#0099cc</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Primary Color 2 is #OOffcc</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="colorBlocks">
  <div>
    <span>#cc0000</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Primary Color 2 is #OOffcc</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, to do this on all spans and look for any hex value within them, remove the `:first-child` selector and use a regular expression to find the hexadecimal value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colorBlocks div span').css('background-color', function() {
    return /#[0-9A-F]{6}/gi.exec($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colorBlocks">
  <div>
    <span>#0099cc</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Primary Color 2 is #00ffcc</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="colorBlocks">
  <div>
    <span>#cc0000</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Primary Color 2 is #00ffcc</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="colorBlocks">
  <div>
    <span>#00cc00</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Primary Color 3 is not specified</span>
  </div>
</div>
```